# Why are my fragments' UI not switching? (incl github repo with code)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to get a handle on Android views and switching thereof. It seems that this should be simple, but....

I am using the ADK. I created an project, ViewsToAKill, with 'Blank Activity with Fragment'. I left the names as default. I then added a new Activity with Fragment named "NextActivity".

I did not touch the Activity java classes. The rest is below. The question is this. When I click on the Go button, I expect "Goodbye!" to replace "Hello!". Instead I see the "Hello!" and the Go button, and I also see "Goodbye!" partially hidden under the button. Why?

```
$ cat app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.rrk.viewstoakill.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</fragment>
$ 
$ cat app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_view"
        android:text="Hello!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hello_view"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
$ 
$ cat app/src/main/res/layout/activity_next.xml
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.rrk.viewstoakill.NextActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
$ 
$ 
$ cat app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_next.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rrk.viewstoakill.NextActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="Goodbye!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
$ 
$ cat app/src/main/java/com/rrk/viewstoakill/MainActivityFragment.java
package com.rrk.viewstoakill;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_go);

        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment nextFragment = new NextActivityFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
$ 
$ cat app/src/main/java/com/rrk/viewstoakill/NextActivityFragment.java

package com.rrk.viewstoakill;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class NextActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public NextActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_next, container, false);
    }
}

$
```

Comment: See https://github.com/rkiddy/ViewsToAKill.git

Comment: Includes the suggestion below, showing how this does not work.

Comment: put the fragment in the framelayout instead of the other way around (in the main activity layout). What is happening is that the container of the next fragment (the FrameLayout) is included in the layout of the first Fragment. Therefore, the `replace` operation does not remove the first fragment, because it is not in the `R.id.container` (the framelayout)

Comment: The first and second suggestions below, together, solve the display problem. I have pushed final version, with screenshots, to the repo above. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically go

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.rrk.viewstoakill.MainActivityFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: This works, in conjunction with the background attribute above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `background` attribute in the fragment's xml layout file?

```
android:background="?android:windowBackground"
```

Comment: In which fragment are you suggesting I do this? Both? I have not seen (AFAIK) this attribute being used but I will try it. It seems odd that one would need this. The default behavior looks obviously wrong and why would that be ok? We will see.

Comment: Interesting. I added the attribute to both of the RelativeLayout objects in the fragments. Previously I would click on Go and see "Hello!", the button, and "Goodbye!" on the screen, mixed together. Now I click on the button and I see the button and "Goodbye!" behind it. In other words, the button (which is only defined in the main fragment and not the next fragment) persists. But the "Hello!" text went away. So, that is better.....

Comment: Add this to all of your fragments.

Comment: I did all the attribute to both of the fragments. As I said, the "Hello" disappeared but the button did not. I am assuming you are saying that I should put the attribute on the RelativeLayout objects in the fragments' XML. If not, let me know.

Comment: this is a shot in the dark. the OP describes that the `replace` operation of the transaction appears to be leaving the original fragment in place, and adding the new one on top.

Comment: Then "Basically go" suggestion below works, but this attribute is necessary for it to do the right thing.